# Prove $a_n = n$ doesn't have any accumulation point

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

This is the question:

> Prove $a_n = n$ doesn't have any accumulation point

I don't know whether my proof is correct or not. Please mention my flaws and if there are other ways, write them.

My proof: Suppose, to the contrary, that $c$ is an accumulation point of $a_n$, and that a subsequence ${a_{n_k}}$ converges to $c$. Notice that ${a_{n_k}} = n_k$. So $n_k$ should be a bounded sequence. This means:

$\exists M\gt 0 :\ \ \forall k \in \mathbb{N} \ \ \ n_k \le M$

If we negate this statement, it becomes:

$\forall M\gt 0 \ \ \exists k \in \mathbb{N}: \ \ \ n_k \gt M$

Let $k = \lfloor M \rfloor +1$. Then $n_{\lfloor M \rfloor +1} \ge \lfloor M \rfloor +1 \gt M$. Therefore, it contradicts the boundedness of sequence and consequently convergence of $a_{n_k}$.

Also, I don't know how to prove $n_{\lfloor M \rfloor +1} \ge \lfloor M \rfloor +1$ rigorously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $1\leq n_1<n_2<n_3<\dots$ from which it can be deduced with induction on $k$ that $n_k\geq k$ for every $k$.

So for $M\in\mathbb R$ just choose an integer $k_M$ with $k_M>M$.

Then $n_k\geq k> M$ for every $k\geq k_M$.

Comment: The induction hypotheses is $n_k \ge k$ and we should prove $n_{k+1} \ge k+1$. So $n_{k+1} \ge n_k + 1 \ge k+1$. How we can prove $n_{k+1} \ge n_k + 1$ for every $k$?

Comment: @S.H.W If $(a_n)_n$ is a sequence with $a_1<a_2<a_3<\cdots$ then for every subsequence $(a_{n_k})_k$ we have $a_{n_1}<a_{n_2}<a_{n_3}<\cdots$ (because by definition of subsequence we have $n_1<n_2<n_3<\cdots$). In special case $a_n=n$ this results in $n_1<n_2<n_3<\cdots$.

Comment: That's right but I want use induction as you wrote. For the proving that statement, we should show for every $k$, $\ \ \ n_{k+1} \ge n_k + 1$.

Comment: The induction is not for proving $1\leq n_1<n_2<n_3<\cdots$. That is a fact (shown in my former comment) and that fact can be used to prove $n_k\geq k$. Base case: $1\leq n_1$ (as part of the fact). Induction step: $n_{k+1}>n_k$ (as part of the fact) combined with $n_k\geq k$ (induction hypothese) amounts in $n_{k+1}>k$ hence $n_{k+1}\geq k+1$. Now it is proved by induction on $k$ that $n_k\geq k$ for every positive integer $k$.

Comment: Okay thanks. Can you explain how $n_{k+1} \gt k$ implies $n_{k+1} \ge k+1$?

Comment: $n_{k+1}$ and $k$ both denote integers. If $a$ and $b$ are integers with $a>b$ then $a\geq b+1$ because $b<a<b+1$ contradicts that $a$ is an integer. E.g. no integer $m$ exists with $4<m<5$.

Comment: I've got it. So $k = \lfloor M \rfloor + 1$ is a valid choice? And other parts of my answer is correct?

Comment: Yes, $k=\lfloor M\rfloor+1$ is valid and your proof is in principle correct.

Comment: Okay, I really appreciate your help.

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Use the fact that $$n_{k+1}\ge n_k+1$$then, can $n_k$ be bounded above?

Comment: How can we get the contradiction by $n_k  \le M$?

Comment: We can prove that $$n_{\lfloor M\rfloor+1}\ge n_{\lfloor M\rfloor}+1\ge n_{\lfloor M\rfloor-1}+2\ge \cdots \ge n_{1}+\lfloor M\rfloor\ge \lfloor M\rfloor+1>M$$